# Why is the number incremented by 2, instead of my specified 1?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code in React:

```
let guest = 0;

function Cup() {
  guest = guest + 1;
  return <h2>Tea cup for guest #{guest}</h2>;
}

export default function TeaSet() {
  return (
    <>
      <Cup />
      <Cup />
      <Cup />
    </>
  );
}
```

I expected the result to be:

```
Tea cup for guest #1
Tea cup for guest #2
Tea cup for guest #3
```

However, the following is returned:

```
Tea cup for guest #2,
Tea cup for guest #4,
Tea cup for guest #6
```

Why is `guest` incremented by 2, instead of the 1 I specified?

Comment: If you're using React's strict mode then components render twice in a development build.  Is that the case here?

Comment: React may call your component an arbitrary amount of times, in any order. You should not rely on global state - pass `guest` as a parameter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The global state variable might not be a viable approach to achieve this.

As far you have mentioned problem in your question you can try passing `param` as a `count`

```js
const  Cup  = ({guestCount}) => {
    return <h2>Tea cup for guest #{guestCount}</h2>;
}

export default function TeaSet() {
  return (
    <>
    <Cup guestCount={1} />
    <Cup guestCount={2}/>
    <Cup guestCount={3}/>
    </>
  );
}
```